# What is the best alternative datatype for (unsigned int) that can be of the same size across 32/64 bit platforms?

Tags: casting, 32bit-64bit, type-conversion

I am developing on 64-bit machine and I realized `unsigned long` does not have the same size on 64/32 platforms. What is the alternative to it while maintaining the max possible data range ?

Answer (score 1):

use uint64_t you are sure it is the same everywere

```
#include <stdint.h> 
uint64_t my_number;
```

Comment: And then I do the type casting ?

Comment: You should replace all your unsigned long by uint64_t. Otherwise you can cast them but it seems useless as you will put small values (long) in a big container (uint64).